# Is there a way to decorate a class injecting a parent class?

Tags: python

I have a base class `A`, and a decorator `behavior`. Both has different behaviors but sometimes it can be used at the same time.

There is to implement a new class decorator `new_behavior` that applies `behavior` and "inject" `A` as a parent class?

Something like this:

```py
@new_behavior
class B:
    ...
```

So `B` will behave just like if it was declared like `class B(A):` but `B` also inhirts all `@behavior` behaviors?

Comment: Can you clarify what your `behavior` decorator does to `A`? Does it return the original class (perhaps after modifying it) or does it return something new (e.g. another class)? Would inheriting those changes from `A` do all the modification needed for `B`, or does the decorator need to be applied again? Do either `A` or `B` have other base classes already?

Comment: There is a simples way to express my question here: lets suppose that I want an "alias" to inhirit classes. Instead of doint `class A(pydantic.BaseModel)` I want to do decorate A with `@base_model` decorator. How can I do it? This is simpler than my original question and practically solve my problem.

Comment: Decorators can do nearly anything they want to the object they're called on, so the details are likely to matter a lot. If you really want an answer about `pydantic`, you should probably include that in the question and add it as a tag. I don't know that module at all, so I can't help much with the specifics.

Comment: The base class I want is irrelevant, all I want is to "inject" an inheritance using a decorantor...

Comment: I'm still playing with the possibility so I won't write it as an answer yet, but it looks like you should be able to have your decorator return a metaclass from the type() function, and injecting the additional inheritance into the second parameter.   It also appears that directly updating cls.\_\_bases\_\_ will update the \_\_mro\_\_,.  Not sure it will give the behaviors you want without more info though.  See also:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477311/inheriting-from-decorated-classes

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, by the time a decorator gets a chance to operate on a class, it's too late to change fundamental properties of the class, like its bases. But that doesn't necessarily mean you can't do what you want, it only rules out direct approaches.

You could have your decorator create a new class with the desired bases, and add the contents of the old class to the new one. But there are a lot of subtle details that might go wrong, like methods that don't play correctly with `super` and other stuff that make it somewhat challenging. I would not want to do this on a whim.

One possible option that might be simpler than most is to make a new class that inherits from both the class you're decorating, and the base class you want to add. That isn't exactly the same as injecting a base class as a base of the decorated, but it will usually wind up with the same MRO, and `super` should work just fine. Here's how I'd implement that:

```
def new_behavior(cls):
    class NewClass(cls, A):    # do the multiple inheritance by adding A here
        pass
    NewClass.__name__ = f'New{cls.__name__}' # should modify __qualname__ too
    return NewClass
```

I'm not applying any other decorators in that code, but you could do that by changing the last line to `return some_other_decorator(NewClass)` or just applying the decorator to the `class` statement with `@decorator` syntax. In order to make introspection nicer, you might want to modify a few parameters of `NewClass` before returning it. I demonstrate altering the `__name__` attribute, but you would probably also want to change `__qualname__` (which I've skipped doing because it would be a bit more fiddly and annoying to get something appropriate), and maybe some others that I can't think of off the top of my head.